# Jupyter Notebook cell - Repeat same imports?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have multiple Notebook cells where im importing the same libraries.
Is there a way to import these libraries once (like in the very 1st cell) and allow all other cells to use them?

Since my notebook has several cells, each importing the same libraries, i'm starting to see alot of redundancies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! You can add all your libraries at the very top of your notebook. All of them will be available for use.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matolotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
```

Comment: So does this mean the entire Notebook is like a single python script, regardless of the number of cells?

Comment: Is not a single python script, but once you declare a variable or import a package, it will be available in your environment once that cell runs.